# Undo'ing some network setups including 'promisc' mode

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, debian, linux-networking

Suppose I have the following script, roughly it sets up promisc mode and setup a bridge between the two networks (acting as a routing point on the mac level in a sense).

```
## set interfaces to promiscuous mode
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 promisc up
ifconfig eth1 0.0.0.0 promisc up

## add both interfaces to the virtual bridge network
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth0
brctl addif br0 eth1

## optional: configure an ip to the bridge to allow remote access
ifconfig br0 192.168.0.111 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
route add default gw 192.168.0.1 dev br0
```

script was seen [here](https://calomel.org/network_loss_emulation.html)

Suppose I need to to 'turn off' the promisc mode again (creating another script to turn it off) or go back the previous configuration, is there some clever way to accomplish that ?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `ifconfig` and `route` anymore (as they have been deprecated in Linux for many years and are no longer installed by default on modern Linux systems) and should rewrite those to use the current `ip` commands.

After that you can disable promiscuous mode with something like:

```
ip link set eth0 promisc off
```

Comment: Also, the interface is automatically put in promiscuous oper state (rather than admin state) when enslaved to a bridge: there's no need to ever write the word "promisc". This can be checked by not setting the interface in promiscuous mode manually and then running `ip -details link show dev eth0` which will include in its result `promiscuity 1` instead of `promiscuity 0` as soon as enslaved (whatever the method/api) and will revert to `promiscuity 0` when removed from the bridge. It's not possible to turn the operative state off while enslaved by trying to administratively turn it off.

Comment: @A.B when I do "netstat -i" it does not seem to be in promisc mode - is that implied then, can you elaborate ?

Comment: @darune I gave in my comment the precise command to type. As Michael Hampton wrote, older Linux commands should be avoided (including netstat which can be replaced by `ss` and `ip`). They use an older APIs becoming obsolete. Those APIs don't provide the information. The P flag is the administrative promiscuous state, not the operational promiscuous state. The oper state can only be seen with newer tools.

Comment: @A.B that is briliant, just checking, thank you !